# Retrieve data of Pod spec into a structure variable

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I have been trying to retrieve pod details & fill those details into fields of the struct. However, I do get errors while filling the details into a struct.

```golang
package main

import (
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    // corev1"k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
)

type PodsList struct{
    podNamespace    string
    podName     string
}

func main() {
   var targetPods []TargetPodsList
   
   config, inClusterConfigError := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if inClusterConfigError != nil {
        fmt.Println("Retrieval of K8s InCluster Config not successful")
        log.Fatal(inClusterConfigError)
    }

    // Set k8s client configuration
    clientset, clientSetError := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if clientSetError != nil {
        fmt.Println("K8s Client for Incluster Configuration not successful")
        log.Fatal(clientSetError)
    }

    // Retrieve Pods for all target K8s nodes
    for index := range targetNodes.TargetNodes {
        targetPodsList, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(metav1.ListOptions{
            FieldSelector: "spec.nodeName=" + someNodeName)
        for podIndex := range targetPodsList.Items {
            targetPods.podNamespace = targetPods[podIndex].podNamespace
            targetPods.podName = targetPods[podIndex].podName
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is a basic thing which I may be missing. Please do suggest and correct my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the code is here.

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/rest"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
    // creates the in-cluster configuration
    config, err := rest.InClusterConfig()
    if err != nil {
        // creates the out-of-cluster config
        var kubeconfig *string
        if home := os.Getenv("HOME"); home != "" {
            kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
        } else {
            kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
        }
        flag.Parse()

        // use the current context in kubeconfig
        config, err = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }

    // creates the clientset
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // fetch all pod name, namespace in "default" namespace
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    for _, pod := range pods.Items {
        fmt.Printf("pod name: %s namespace: %s\n", pod.ObjectMeta.GetName(), pod.ObjectMeta.GetNamespace())
    }
}
```

run this code.

```bash
$ kubectl get pod
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-pod    1/1     Running   0          92m
nginx-pod2   1/1     Running   0          21s

$ go run main.go
pod name: nginx-pod namespace: default
pod name: nginx-pod2 namespace: default
```

and you can see client-go examples [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Bell, thanks for your response.
However, I was able to print the pod details without any issue.
I would like to use this pod information and fill into a text/template format.
For which, i am not able to save this particular information into a struct.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by the "text/template" format? for example, case of the use "html/template" package? https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/

Comment: What i'm doing is..
Retrieve PodSpec information for pods in a particular node. 
I want to use podSpec information and use this in text/template for filling the exact fields in a particular message. 

For filling exact fields, we may have to use a struct kind of variables while using text/template or html/template. 

Now while getting this information to be stored in a particular variable, it always fails for me, with my code.

Comment: I posted to my gist what updated script. Could you review it? I changed to be able to specify node name and output using HTML template.

https://gist.github.com/bells17/48fe549d52160e43a5db6ab363a27b55